# CreateParam does not have an implementation

Tags: sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to run the Sqllite inmemory database together with ServiceStack.

Console App in Visual Studio .net 4.6.1

(if I run the same code in LinqPad it is working fine)

Platform target: x64

Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteDialect.Provider;

    using (IDbConnection db = ":memory:".OpenDbConnection())
    {

    }
}
```

Then running this app, I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
 ConsoleApplication1.exe

Additional information: Method 'CreateParam' in type     
  'ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider' 
   from assembly 
  'ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteNET, 
   Version=4.0.42.0, 
   Culture=neutral,     
   PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

package.json:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="ServiceStack.Common" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="ServiceStack.Interfaces" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64" version="4.0.42" targetFramework="net461" />
   <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you post your packages.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all versions of ServiceStack you need to **reference the same version** for all ServiceStack packages. Your packages.json shows that it's referencing the older v4.0.42 of the deprecated [ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite64) NuGet package.

Both **OrmLite.Sqlite64** and **OrmLite.Sqlite32** have been deprecated into the **ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows** NuGet package which contains 32bit and 64bit native .dlls.

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows
```

You can also use the **ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Mono** Sqlite NuGet package which works on both Linux and Windows and references the native `sqlite3.dll`.